# Npgsql Exception while reading from stream

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using Npgsql 3.1.7 since yesterday when I have updated it to 3.1.8 via Nuget but I get the same exception.

I'm connecting to a remote Windows server 2012 and Postgresql 9.5 also tried Postgresql 9.4 on Debian 8 with the same behavior.

What I'm trying to do is to select data via COPY(select..) command using Npgsql BeginBinaryExport but after some seconds the exception is thrown. This happens every run.
I tried to apply `Pooling=false,Keepalive=10, commandtimeout=0` to the connection string without success.

I'm getting:

> Exception while reading from stream Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: Unable to establish     connection. Wrong answer
>   from the connected part after a timeout interval or     missing
>   response.

This last part is in italian, I tried to translate it, I hope you can     understand it anyway.

Here the StackTrace:

> Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' in Npgsql.dll in 
>   Npgsql.ReadBuffer.Ensure(Int32 count, Boolean dontBreakOnTimeouts) in
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean isPrependedMessage) in 
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageWithPrepended(DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode) in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpectingT in
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryExporter..ctor(NpgsqlConnector connector, String
>   copyToCommand) in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.BeginBinaryExport(String
>   copyToCommand)

I tried to change the command from COPY(select ...) to a simple select using `NpgsqlCommand` and it works, but if I remove `Pooling=false,Keepalive=10, commandtimeout=0` from the connection string the exception returns.

EDIT:
The code I'm using is:

```
using (var reader = connection.BeginBinaryExport("COPY (select * from \"DTC_Det\") TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)")){ ... }
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code you are using? What's your COPY statement, are you specifying `TO STDOUT` and `(FORMAT BINARY)`, like this? 

`Conn.BeginBinaryExport("COPY data (field_text, field_int2) TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)"))`

Comment: code added to the question.

Comment: Is `DTC_Det` a view?  As far as I know, there is no way to set a timeout property on a Begin Text/Binary Import/Export, but if you are doing a raw import/export of a table, it should hardly be necessary.  If this is a view, then that's a horse of a different color

Comment: thanks for the answer. DTC_Det is not a view, it is a normal table

Answer (score 1):

string connectionString = Host=servername;Username=postgres;Password=password;Database=postgres;port=1234;Timeout=50;

It will work in c#.